# Delicious English Only

Tags: bookmarklet, delicious-api

How I can see English only bookmarks on Delicious? They don't have built-in support as of now.
http://support.delicious.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=2218

Is it possible via Javascript Bookmarklet or by some API?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure try Google Advanced Search and set the language to be "**English**"

You can search using

> search term site:delicious.com

Comment: No you cannot search delicious links/bookmarks on Google.
On Yahoo, it shows the links in the words but it is not reliable.. for example:
searching for "intelligence" got me "intel" to. as "delicious.com/tag/Intel" along with some 'intelligence' results.
Even on altavista did the same thing.  
Bing didn't strip the word, but it added the words. Example: delicious.com/tag/businessintelligence.

I am now thinking about reliability of search engines.